# Two plot using the same axis and moving one in different positions maybe up or down or

Tags: r

I want to move the Boxplot at the top of the ecdf.
and maybe also reduce the size of the boxplot too.But have no idea on how to do it.This is my code so far that I have been able to generate and a picture attach to it.
Thanks

```
data3 <- data.frame( BG1 = c(78,87 ,82, 93,78,82,84,79,85,82 ,93, 85, 131))
data3

library("reshape2")                                                 # Load reshape2

dd3 <- melt(data3) # Reshaping data frame
dd3
ggp67<- ggplot(dd3 , aes(x = value)) + 
  stat_ecdf(geom = "step")+
  stat_boxplot(geom = 'errorbar' , width=0.5) + geom_boxplot(fill=c("pink"),outlier.size = 2) +
  labs(x="Blutzucker-Werte (mg/dl)" ,y=" "  ,
       title = "Die empirische Verteilungsfunktion und Boxplot für Blutzucker Gruppe 1 " ) +  
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) 
 
ggp67
```

[image]

Comment: it's unclear to me what you mean with 'move the boxplot at the top of the ecdf' and 'reduce the size of the boxplot'. Could you provide a sketch of how you want it to look like?

Comment: you should add "library(ggplot)" to your code.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
data3 <- data.frame( BG1 = c(78,87 ,82, 93,78,82,84,79,85,82 ,93, 85, 131))

ggplot(data3 , aes(x = BG1)) + 
  stat_ecdf(geom = "step")+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=BG1, y=1.1), fill=c("pink"),outlier.size = 2, width=.1) +
  
  labs(x="Blutzucker-Werte (mg/dl)" ,y=" "  ,
       title = "Die empirische Verteilungsfunktion und Boxplot für Blutzucker Gruppe 1 " ) + 
  theme_classic() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))  + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1,by=.25))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Perhaps your real-world use is more complicated, but you don't need to reshape the data with `melt()` here.

Comment: ah okay, thanks a lot,i guess it is because of the way you define y on the aes of the boxplot.